# Dynamically expanding width of a dynamically loaded DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a tooltip that is loaded dynamically based on server side data. It's been working well until I got to much larger SKUs. Now there is overflow.

I'm trying to use either CSS or JS to dynamically change the width to eliminate the overflow as shown in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eComEvo/01tz6adv/1/).

My HTML:

```
<div class="ext-tooltip 12345-789-1456789-431535" data-sku="12345-789-1456789-431535">
  <div class="tooltip-stock">12345-789-1456789-431535 :: 5</div>
</div>
<div id="invoice-lines">
    <div id="progress-container" class="hide" style="display: none;">
        <div class="progress-bar-container">
            <div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar-progress" style="width: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="example ta_center">Loading...</div>
    </div>
<table cellspacing="0" id="invoice-time" class="invoice-lines spreadsheet" style="display:none"></table>
```

My CSS:

```
.ext-tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0059/3992/t/14/assets/oem-icon.png?17543244824127338148) -78px 0 no-repeat;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0 10px 7px 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  line-height: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 9pt;
}
```

My JS:

```
var $tooltip = $('.ext-tooltip.12345-789-1456789-431535');

$tooltip.innerWidth($('.tooltip-stock', $tooltip).innerWidth());
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `no-repeat` from the `background` rule allows the width to adjust to different lengths of text.

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/01tz6adv/3/)